# Spring CSRF token does not work, when the request to be sent is a multipart request

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-security, csrf, csrf-protection

I use,

- Spring Framework 4.0.0 RELEASE (GA)
- Spring Security 3.2.0 RELEASE (GA)
- Struts 2.3.16

In which, I use an in-built security token to guard against CSRF attacks.

The Struts form looks like the following.

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side"
        action="Category"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        method="POST"
        validate="true"
        id="dataForm"
        name="dataForm">

    <s:hidden name="%{#attr._csrf.parameterName}"
              value="%{#attr._csrf.token}"/>
</s:form>
```

The generated HTML code is as follows.

```
<form id="dataForm"
      name="dataForm"
      action="/TestStruts/admin_side/Category.action"
      method="POST"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden"
           name="_csrf"
           value="3748c228-85c6-4c3f-accf-b17d1efba1c5" 
           id="dataForm__csrf">
</form>
```

**This works fine, unless the request is multipart** in which case, the request ends with the status code 403.

> **HTTP Status 403** - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request
>   parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message** Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter
>   '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
>
> **description** Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.

The `spring-security.xml` file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http pattern="/Login.jsp*" security="none"></http>

    <http auto-config='true' use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <session-management session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true" />
        </session-management>

        <csrf/>

        <headers>
            <xss-protection />
            <frame-options />
            <!--<cache-control />-->
            <!--<hsts />-->
            <content-type-options /> <!--content sniffing-->
        </headers>

        <intercept-url pattern="/admin_side/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" requires-channel="any"/>
        <form-login login-page="/admin_login/Login.action" authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/admin_login/Login.action" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>

    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loginSuccessHandler" class="loginsuccesshandler.LoginSuccessHandler"/>
    <beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="loginsuccesshandler.AuthenticationFailureHandler" />

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="false" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <protect-pointcut expression="execution(* admin.dao.*.*(..))" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    </global-method-security>
</beans:beans>
```

So, where to look for this token, when a request is multipart? (This should not be related to Struts at all.)

<sub>The implementation of `UserDetailsService` can be found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20919913/1391249) earlier question of mine, if needed.</sub>

---

[Placing `MultipartFilter` before Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipartfilter) did not help either.

The `web.xml` file looks like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>AdminLoginNocacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.AdminLoginNocacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AdminLoginNocacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin_login/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.NoCacheFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>NoCacheFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin_side/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <description>Description</description>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>struts.devMode</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

It only works, when the token is appended as a query-string parameter as follows which is however, discouraged.

```
<s:form namespace="/admin_side"
        action="Category?%{#attr._csrf.parameterName}=%{#attr._csrf.token}"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        method="POST"
        validate="true"
        id="dataForm"
        name="dataForm">
    ...
<s:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, since it is a multipart request in which the CSRF token is unavailable to Spring security unless `MultipartFilter` along with `MultipartResolver` is properly configured so that the multipart request can be processed by Spring.

`MulipartResolver` in the `applicationContext.xml` file has to be registered as follows

```
<bean id="filterMultipartResolver" 
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"> 

    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="-1" />
</bean>
```

The attribute value `-1` of `maxUploadSize` puts no limit on the uploaded file size. This value may vary depending upon the requirements. In case of multiple files, the file size is the size of all uploaded files.

---

Also,

```
<servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
```

of `<filter-mapping>` of `MultipartFilter` needs to be changed to

```
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

This is a [bug](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2466) in the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipartfilter).

This will work just fine, in case, it is Spring MVC alone.

but if it is an integration of Spring and Struts(2), it incurs another problem in the associated Struts action class. The information of the uploaded file will be `null` in the associated Struts action class(es).

To solve this particular issue, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21741353/1391249) answer to customize a [multipart request](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/multipart/MultiPartRequest.html).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using @annotations, and the jsp view like this:

```
    <form:form id="profileForm" action="profile?id=${param.id}" method="POST" 
          modelAttribute="appUser" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
             ...
            <input type="file" name="file">
             ...
            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                value="${_csrf.token}" />
    </form:form>
```

this may help:

AppConfig.java :

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
public class AppConfig {

   @Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver")
   public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
      CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
      filterMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
      // resolver.setMaxUploadSize(512000);
      return filterMultipartResolver;
}
...
```

The SecurityConfig.java extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and is the configuration for SpringSecurity

The multipart/form-data filter (MultipartFilter) needs to be registered before the SecurityConfig that enables the CSRF. You can do it with this:

SecurityInitializer.java:

```
public class SecurityInitializer extends
AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
   super.beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);

   // CSRF for multipart form data filter:
   FilterRegistration.Dynamic springMultipartFilter;
   springMultipartFilter = servletContext.addFilter(
    "springMultipartFilter", new MultipartFilter());
   springMultipartFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by:

- sending the multi-part file using vanilla javascript, like in [Mozilla's guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript#Dealing_with_binary_data)
- adding the _csrf token in the HTML header, in meta tags, like in the Spring guideline for [sending the CSRF token with Ajax](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token-ajax)
- instead of using jquery, adding it directly to the XHR object

  ```
  var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
  var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
  XHR.setRequestHeader(csrfHeader, csrfToken);
  XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);

  XHR.send(data);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

In case of Spring Boot + Security + CSRF + Multipart,  multipart files get binding to neither ModelAttribure nor RequestParam (MultipartFile file)

Below Code Worked fine for me.

**1.MvcConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter { 

.......
......

/*
     * Case : Spring Boot + Security + CSRF + Mulitpart 
     * In this case, since it is a multipart request in which the CSRF token is unavailable to Spring security unless MultipartFilter along with MultipartResolver 
     * is properly configured so that the multipart request can be processed by Spring.
     * 
     * And 
     * 
     * The multipart/form-data filter (MultipartFilter) needs to be registered before the SecurityConfig that enables the CSRF.
     * So that's why 
     * 1. reg.setOrder(1); //below
     * 2. security.filter-order=2 // in application.properties
     */

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean registerMultipartFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean reg = new FilterRegistrationBean(new MultipartFilter());
        reg.setOrder(1);
        return reg;
    }

    @Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver filterMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        filterMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        // resolver.setMaxUploadSize(512000);
        return filterMultipartResolver;
    }
.....
.....
}
```

**2. application.properties**

```
security.filter-order=2
```

Answer (score -6):

You can disable csrf - httpSecurity.csrf().disable();

```
 @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        ...
        httpSecurity.csrf().disable();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No. disabling that token is not a solution. It will wide open the CSRF hole.