# InvalidCsrfTokenException when submitting a form

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-security, csrf

I'm working in a spring based web application (version 4.1.6.RELEASE, spring security 4.0.0.RELEASE) and I'm getting the error `InvalidCsrfTokenException: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.` after submitting a form (POST method). According to the [spring's documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/html/taglibs.html#the-csrfinput-tag) "Spring Security automatically inserts a CSRF form field for any `<form:form>` tags you use", so why I'm getting this exception?
Thanks in advance.

This is my spring security configuration:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">
<http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <headers>
        <frame-options/>
        <xss-protection/>
        <hsts/>
    </headers>
    <csrf/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <!-- some others urls to intercept -->
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/login" />
    </session-management>
</http>
```

And this is the definition of my form (excluding the fields it contains):

```
<form:form action="myaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formId" modelAttribute="myBean">
</form:form>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hi @smoggers, thank you so much for this link, please post your comment as an answer an I will accept it, regards

Comment: ok, glad it solved your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is arising because you are using a **multi-part** form. Please see the accepted answer here:

[Spring CSRF token does not work, when the request to be sent is a multipart request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514074/spring-csrf-token-does-not-work-when-the-request-to-be-sent-is-a-multipart-requ)