# Spring Boot + Security - Can't upload file (Multipart) when CSRF is enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, multipart

I want to upload files from my angularJS client. I have enabled CSRF protection and it works fine except when i try to upload a file, where i get a `403` error:

> Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf'
>   or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.

But the token is in the request headers and is correct! When i disable the CSRF protection i can upload the files without any problem.

The CSRF protection works fine besides that.

Here is my current configuration:

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityUserDetailsService securityUserDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private AjaxAuthSuccessHandler ajaxAuthSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authFailureHandler)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/index.html",
                        "/styles/**",
                        "/bower_components/**",
                        "/scripts/**"
                ).permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxAuthSuccessHandler).permitAll()
                .and().httpBasic()
                .and().addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
                .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(securityUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

}
```

**CsrfHeaderFilter.java**

```
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
        if (csrf != null) {
            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
            String token = csrf.getToken();
            if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

And last i have added a SecurityWebApplicationInitializer as pointed [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-multipart).

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.java**

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
    }

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

**Update:** i added this config but i still get a 403.

```
@Configuration
public class MultipartUploadConfig {

    @Bean(name = "filterMultipartResolver")
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    }
}
```

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514074/spring-csrf-token-does-not-work-when-the-request-to-be-sent-is-a-multipart-requ

Comment: @smoggers i tried that but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @inanutshellus no. i gave up and disabled CSRF for the time being...

Comment: @ChristosBaziotis: I found a solution (I've tested it with Spring Boot) and will mark this questions as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514074/spring-csrf-token-does-not-work-when-the-request-to-be-sent-is-a-multipart-requ/43122490#43122490

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring CSRF token does not work, when the request to be sent is a multipart request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514074/spring-csrf-token-does-not-work-when-the-request-to-be-sent-is-a-multipart-requ)

Answer (score 2):

A quick solution if you are OK with sending the CSRF Token as a url parameter. In your html template.

```
<form .... th:action="@{/upload(${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token})}">
...
</form>
```

Comment: @ChristosBaziotis: They are on answering spree -> [same answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34762285/1700321).

Comment: that's exposing the token in the URL, bad practice

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ajax, put token parameter in url, to action in form action:

```
url: "/uploadFile?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"
```

It becomes like this:

```
function uploadFile() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/uploadFile?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData($("#upload-file-form")[0]),
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function () {
          // Handle upload success
          $("#upload-file-message").text("File succesfully uploaded");
        },
        error: function () {
          // Handle upload error
          $("#upload-file-message").text(
              "File not uploaded (perhaps it's too much big)");
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: that's exposing the token in the URL, bad practice

Comment: With Ajax, you can just add it to the request headers, like explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514074/spring-csrf-token-does-not-work-when-the-request-to-be-sent-is-a-multipart-requ/43122490#43122490

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to provide the token on each Ajax call:

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
```

There's another StackOverflow post that talks about this, that's where I found, but it's been a while since I saw it.